# Make tmux point to specific bash bin while keeping zsh as default shell

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux

I have two bash binaries in my system: one in `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` and one in `/bin/bash`.

My default shell is neither, it's zsh. But I use bash for some scripts.

Outside tmux (running in iterm2), `which bash` gives `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` (as I want it to be). But inside tmux it's `/bin/bash`.

What should I do so that `which bash` in tmux gives `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` while keeping zsh as the default shell?

Comment: what do you mean by pointing to. do you the value of `which bash` or do you mean the default shell used by tmux or iterm2.. your wording is quite confusing. because several of these conflict with your desire to keep `zsh` as your default shell.. I take this to mean you are concerned with what a call to `bash` will yield which is a function of your `PATH`

Comment: You forgot to explain what `pointing to` means in your question. I also don't understand why you talk in the title about tmux, but in your question refer also to iterm2. Finally you never explain how your shell is started. We don't even know whether it's a login-shell or a non-login shell.  As it stands, I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: i believe "pointing to /bin/bash" means `which bash` would output `/bin/bash`. not a native english speaker myself and also not quite sure how to describe this correctly. others can help update more. :)

Comment: plz post your zsh rc files: `.zprofile/.zshrc/.zlogin`